# WPF Dependency Object

Tags: wpf

Has anyone ever heard of implementing IDependencyObject instead of inheriting from it -- that way one could actually create a class hierarchy instead of having to use only interfaces when trying to get both dependency object/property and custom behavior on our classes.

I want to have a hierarchy of class kinds that are directly usable in the context of an existing structure, i.e. Polygon.  I want to be able to use my PolyType in any place, and without any more dialogue and indirection that would be required if I place the PolyGon existing type as a Part of  my DependencyObject.  But I also want to be able to have my class as the a) the target of {Binding} markup extension, b) Animate properties of PolyType and c) apply themed styling to PolyType.

I want to implement IDependencyObject instead of being forced to inherit from it directly, and obstructing my ability to be a direct descendent and usable in place of, PolyGon.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is IDependencyObject and what do you mean by implement it instead of inheriting from it?

Comment: @o_weisman To get dependency property behavior I must *inherit* from DependencyObject.  Actually I would like to *inherit* from Object, Polygon perhaps.  But it seems like I should be able to Implement IDependencyObject and get all the benefits of DependencyProperties.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have to inherit from DependencyObject. I use a custom code snippet that generates the following code to register a dependancy property:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
public static DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(Polygon), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MyProperty_Changed)));

public Polygon MyProperty
{
    get { return (Polygon)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}


private static void MyProperty_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    UserControl1 thisClass = (UserControl1)o;
    thisClass.SetMyProperty();
}

private void SetMyProperty()
{
    //Put Instance MyProperty Property Changed code here
}


public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

}

As you can see the DependencyObject can be any type of object. If this is not what you need, please post you code examples, or explain your situation better.

Comment: I don't want Polygon to be a property.  I want to *inherit* from Polygon.

Comment: By the way, you *ARE* inheriting from DependencyObject by inheriting from UserControl.